# How do I make the webcam on a Compaq Presario CQ60 notebok work?

Tags: webcam

How can i make the webcam to work?i mention is not working with skype or kopete.

Computer specs:

- product: Compaq Presario CQ60 Notebook PC
- memory 3.7 GB
- processor AMD Athlon Dual-Core QL-62 × 2
- graphics GeForce 8200M G/PCI/SSE2/3DNOW
- OS type 32-bit
- OS kernel Linux 3.0.0-17-generic
- Release 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot

Answer (score 0):

am using Compaq Presario CQ60 Notebook also and i was having the same problem. You just have to download "Camorama" and here is the code using Terminal

"sudo apt-get install camorama"

Its a small program and it should be complete in a matter of seconds. lauche it and create a folder in "Pictures" directory or wherever you would like to save you photos. go to "Edit" properties of Camorama (On top if you are using ubuntu 11.01" and then click "Preferences" which seem to be the only option under that menu.  click "Local Capture" tab and then "Browse..." button found after "directory for captured pics" textbox. select the folder you created. Thats it you are done